# How to connect Azure Sql Database with Hololens 2

Tags: sql, database, azure, unity-game-engine, hololens

I want to develop an app for `Hololens 2`.

However, I can't connect the Azure SQL Database.

I am thinking I need to use some type of RESTful API for this.

Comment: Having trouble trying to get a clear picture of what you are asking. Can you provide any more information to help improve your question?

Comment: @treckstar I have a database in azure (MySql), and i want to extract data and use it in my hololens aplication. I use Unity to deploy the app.